# Arduino Nano 33 BLE work with its Bluetooth and GPS synchronously?

Tags: serial, adafruit, gps, arduino-nano-ble

I am using Arduino nano 33 Sense BLE in which I want GPS to run and display its location . The GPS module which I am using is Adafruit GPS. I want both Bluetooth and GPS to run synchronously. But only one of them shows output. I have tried Adafruit-GPS library with the Hardware Serial but it shows the GPS location not the Bluetooth working.
I also checked the code individually both are working well.I have used the example of **Adafruit-GPS library->GPS_HardwareSerial_Parsing** and **ArduinoBLE library->LED** , these codes both work individually well but when I have combined them and tried to make it run only the GPS shows its location the bluetooth seems to be not working.Below is the combined code:

```
#include <Adafruit_GPS.h>
#include <ArduinoBLE.h>

// what's the name of the hardware serial port?
#define GPSSerial Serial1
// Connect to the GPS on the hardware port
Adafruit_GPS GPS(&GPSSerial);
// Set GPSECHO to 'false' to turn off echoing the GPS data to the Serial console
// Set to 'true' if you want to debug and listen to the raw GPS sentences
#define GPSECHO false
uint32_t timer = millis();



BLEService ledService("19B10000-E8F2-537E-4F6C-D104768A1214"); // BLE LED Service
// BLE LED Switch Characteristic - custom 128-bit UUID, read and writable by central
BLEByteCharacteristic switchCharacteristic("19B10001-E8F2-537E-4F6C-D104768A1214", BLERead | BLEWrite);
const int ledPin = LED_BUILTIN; // pin to use for the LED



void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);

 // 9600 NMEA is the default baud rate for Adafruit MTK GPS's- some use 4800
  GPS.begin(9600);
  GPS.sendCommand(PMTK_SET_NMEA_OUTPUT_RMCGGA);
  GPS.sendCommand(PMTK_SET_NMEA_UPDATE_1HZ); // 1 Hz update rate

  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  BLE.setLocalName("LED");
  BLE.setAdvertisedService(ledService);
  // add the characteristic to the service
  ledService.addCharacteristic(switchCharacteristic);
  // add service
  BLE.addService(ledService);
  // set the initial value for the characeristic:
  switchCharacteristic.writeValue(0);
  // start advertising
  BLE.advertise();

  delay(1000);
}




void loop() 
{  
  char c = GPS.read();

  BLEDevice central = BLE.central();

  if (GPS.newNMEAreceived()) {
   // Serial.println(GPS.lastNMEA()); // this also sets the newNMEAreceived() flag to false
    if (!GPS.parse(GPS.lastNMEA())) // this also sets the newNMEAreceived() flag to false
      return; // we can fail to parse a sentence in which case we should just wait for another
  }

 if (timer > millis()) timer = millis();


//BLE code to connect to bluetooth

  // if a central is connected to peripheral:
  if (central) {
    Serial.print("Connected to central: ");
    // print the central's MAC address:
    Serial.println(central.address());
    // while the central is still connected to peripheral:
    while (central.connected()) {
      // if the remote device wrote to the characteristic,
      // use the value to control the LED:
      if (switchCharacteristic.written()) {
        if (switchCharacteristic.value()) {   // any value other than 0
          Serial.println("LED on");
          digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);         // will turn the LED on
        } else {                              // a 0 value
          Serial.println(F("LED off"));
          digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);          // will turn the LED off
        }
      }
    }
    // when the central disconnects, print it out:
    Serial.print(F("Disconnected from central: "));
    Serial.println(central.address());
  }


//GPS to print latitude and longitude
  // approximately every 5 seconds or so, print out the current stats
  if (millis() - timer > 5000) {
    timer = millis(); // reset the timer
    Serial.print("Fix: "); Serial.print((int)GPS.fix);
    Serial.print(" quality: "); Serial.println((int)GPS.fixquality);
    if (GPS.fix) {
      Serial.print("Location: ");
      Serial.print(GPS.latitude, 4); Serial.print(GPS.lat);
      Serial.print(", ");
      Serial.print(GPS.longitude, 4); Serial.println(GPS.lon);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: `return; // we can fail to parse` skips the rest of the loop()